# Ignore page navigation confirm dialog when running inside of webpack dev server

Tags: webpack, browser, webpack-dev-server

I am working on a project using the webpack dev server. This project has certain states that prompt the user for confirmation, like so:

```
window.onbeforeunload = () => {
  if (someCondition) {
    return true;
  }
};
```

This makes it so that a prompt appears on refresh, *also when webpack dev server detects code changes,* which is rather inconvenient.

Is there some way to disable confirmation when a refresh is requested by the webpack dev server?

Answer (score 0):

The webpack hot reload exposes the webpackHotUpdate function in the window, so you can *abuse* that.

Have something like this. Make sure it's executed after webpack created the function.

```
var _webpackHotUpdate = window.webpackHotUpdate;
var _hotUpdateFired = false;

window.webpackHotUpdate = function() {
    _hotUpdateFired = true;
    return _webpackHotUpdate.apply(window, arguments)
};
```

That adds a global window variable that switches to true on the call. Then in your handler you just have

```
window.onbeforeunload = () => {
  if (someCondition && !(typeof _hotUpdateFired !== 'undefined' && _hotUpdateFired)) {
    return true;
  }
};
```

A global window variable is a dirty trick, but I'ld say it's fine for development. I've wrapped it in the typeof check so that you could just wrap the first code block in a "if dev" condition, and the second block wouldn't fault in prod, when you don't have this variable.

Comment: At what point does Webpack create this function? I don't see anything bound to my `window`, and the code above doesn't work for me (as of `webpack 4.23.1` anyhow)
Edit: thank you for your answer regardless btw

Comment: I'm using webpack 3.8.1. The setup is likely different in 4th. When I started looking into it, hot replacement was a separate node_module with different stuff exposed (i.e. even more different), though I cannot find it right now.

There are some APIs for HMR in webpack 4.23.1 here, though I don't have time at the moment to look through and make a full self-suffician answer. https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/

The quick look says you can try the addStatusHandler there